# UserForm check the existing list before creating new data

Tags: excel, vba

I'm searching for a way to get only unique ID values in my list controlled via UserForm.

I have plent of textboxes that are filled but one called "CHARGE" should be present only once in my entire list. So i need some check for my macro to start before a new position will be added to my list.

My unique ID is: `Me.E1GCharge`

my code:

```
Private Sub SaveData()
'Copy input values to sheet.
Dim lRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = sheet1
lRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).row
With ws

'ME.E1GCharge should exist only one time in my list. 
'If i try to make by mistake it one more time it should be not possible
    .Cells(lRow, 1).Value = Me.E1GCharge.Value
    .Cells(lRow, 3).Value = Me.E1GMatName.Value
    .Cells(lRow, 4).Value = Me.E1Gtype.Value
    .Cells(lRow, 5).Value = Me.E1GMatNumber.Value
    .Cells(lRow, 6).Value = Format(Me.E1GExpiryDate.Value, "mmm.yyyy")
    .Cells(lRow, 7).Value = Me.E1GBoxPcs.Value
    .Cells(lRow, 8).Value = Me.E1GAmmount.Value
    .Cells(lRow, 9).Value = Me.E1GUnit.Value
    .Cells(lRow, 10).Value = Me.E1Gkonz.Value

End With
'Clear input controls.
Me.E1GMatName.Value = ""
Me.E1Gtype.Value = ""
Me.E1GMatNumber.Value = ""
Me.E1GExpiryDate.Value = ""
Me.E1GBoxPcs.Value = ""
Me.E1GAmmount.Value = ""
Me.E1Gkonz.Value = ""
Me.E1GUnit.Value = ""

Call GetData
```

End Sub

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through all the existing vlaues and check if the Charge you want to add already exists:

```
Dim i as Integer
For i = 1 To lRow
  If ws.Cells(i, 1).Value = Me.E1GCharge.Value then
    Msgbox "This Value already exists!"
    Exit Sub
  End If
next i
```